# Extract text after square brackets

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have a log:

[column3] message

How could i write regular expression to select text afrter square bracket ] without including it in extracted text?

Comment: Possibly through a positive lookbehind > `(?<=]).*`. Give it a [try](https://regex101.com/r/z2lUKX/3) and see if that is what you are after.

Comment: @JvdV  level=fatal msg="error parsing regexp: invalid or unsupported Perl syntax: `(?<`"

Comment: Will your message ever contain square brackets? Sometimes it's simpler to just split: `x.split('] ')[-1]`

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

val = "[column3] message"

obj = re.search(r'\] (.*)', val)

print(obj.group(1))
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with [`regex`](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) library:

```
import regex

str = '[column3] message'
res = regex.search(r'(?<=\[column\d+\]).+', str)
print res.group()
```

**Output:**

```
 message
```